# jQuery file upload and VideoJS record won't upload the file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery file upload plugin and videojs-record plugin to capture the users recording and upload it to the server.
It all works ok and JS does create a blob but the files won't upload.

This is my code:

```
$(function () {
              // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget
              $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                  url: '/php',
                  done: function (e, data) {
                      $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                          var message = 'Upload complete: ' + file.name + ' (' +
                              file.size + ' bytes)';
                          $('<p/>').text(message).appendTo(document.body);
                          console.log(message);
                      });
                  }
              });
              // setup videojs-record
              var player = videojs('myAudio',
              {
                  controls: true,
                  width: 600,
                  height: 300,
                  plugins: {
                      record: {
                          audio: true,
                          video: true,
                          maxLength: 20,
                          debug: true
                      }
                  }
              });
              player.on('finishRecord', function()
              {
                  // the blob object contains the audio data
                  var audioFile = player.recordedData;
                  console.log('finished recording: ', audioFile);
                  // upload data to server
                  var filesList = [audioFile.video];
                  $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: filesList});
              });
          });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your web server's error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm running on localhost using XAMPP